# Rename multiple files using python by reading from a file

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I'm trying to rename multiple audio files in a folder.
What I want to do is to read the new file names from a .txt file and then rename the old file names.
I've a tried, but it seems not working.
So please somebody help me.
I'm using python 3.8.2 & windows

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OS module to rename the file and just run through the names

```
    import os
    new_names = open('file.txt', 'r')
    old_names = ['Put old names here']
    i = 0
    for name in new_names:
        os.rename(r'file path\{}.file_type'.format(name), r'file path\{}.file_type'.format(old_names[i]))
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, could you please mark it answered?